# Is there a way to only append new data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, file-geodatabase

Is there a way to append only newly added records from a database to another database?  I looked online and couldn't find an answer.  I figured this would be somewhat straight forward.    We have a working database that I want only append new records to our 'live' database.  Both of them are File GDB.

---

Update 1
I have two File GDBs.  One is a working GDB where users can make edits.  The other GDB serves as a 'live' GDB which needs to get updated when the 'working' has changes made.  Right now I have to stop the service remove the live database and copy over the working database in it's place, then starting the service again for every client.  I was looking at a way to just copy the updated records so I don't have to stop the service and know that only new updates went to the live database.  Should I put the live database on a SDE?

Comment: checkout and check-in is the only option http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n00000007000000

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to enable editor tracking because (with my bolding) ...

> Through editor tracking, ArcGIS can automatically record the following
>   information for each feature or table record in a geodatabase dataset:
>
> - The name of the user who created it.
> - **The date and time it was created.**
> - The name of the user who edited it.
> - The date and time it was last edited.

The help page named [**About tracking an editor's changes to data**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_tracking_an_editor_s_changes_to_data/01m600000068000000/) is a good place to start reading about this.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I'm currently using editor tracking, but I'm trying to automate the task with python.  I just don't want to be able to write duplicates.

Comment: @joebob Can you edit your Question to describe this requirement about not writing duplicates in more detail, please?